# Sum all row exclude the negative numbers in Oracle Reports

Tags: sql, oracle, oraclereports

I have one table with 10 rows. I want to sum the values in a particular column. But I want to exclude all the negative numbers.

How can I sum just the positive numbers and ignore the negative numbers?

This is my pictures example:
[image: sample]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like

```
SELECT SUM( case when column_name > 0 
                 then column_name
                 else 0
              end ) sum_of_non_negative
  FROM table_name
```

Comment: but how to do in designer not in the sql. For example i have table with +/- number. but how to sum all without sum the negatif number?.

Comment: @AminSCO - What do you mean by "in designer not in the SQL"?

Comment: @ Justin Cave- i mean in the report. because im using the variable to sum all the row.

Answer (score 6):

With your specifications,

```
Select sum(col) 
from table 
where col>0;
```

Comment: but how to do in designer not in the sql. For example i have table with +/- number. but how to sum all without sum the negatif number?.

Comment: I don't know, you should exclude row 22 from result set. Do you need it in the result set?

Comment: you can use another fake column with value `case when column_name > 0 
                 then column_name
                 else 0
              end` and make the sum on it. I can't help you on oraclereports.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select sum(col) 
from table 
where col>0
AND   col not like '-%';
```